# Complex vectors: parallelism, orthogonality and coplanarity

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Do these conditions exist for complex vectors (where each component is complex)?
If so, what are the formulas to find whether the conditions are true between two (or 3) given complex vectors?

More information:
I am writing a general purpose vector class. I found out that there is a formula for the orthogonality condition between two complex vectors, which is based on the assumption that the dot product is defined to be anti linear to its first argument. I was wondering if such a general formula exists for the parallelism condition. solitaryroad.com/c135.html. The idea is that I dont have control over what properties a complex vector holds, thats something that the user decides. For example, they could decide what complex dot product definition to use based on their use case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In particular, some examples of real and complex vectors that have/don't have the properties you want could help.

Comment: I am writing a general purpose vector class. I found out that there is a formula for the orthogonality between two comples vectors, which is based on the assumption that the dot product is defined to be anti linear to its first argument. I was wondering if such a general formula exists for the parallelism condition. https://solitaryroad.com/c135.html.  
The idea is that I dont have control over what properties a complex vector holds, thats something that the user decides. For example, they could decide what complex dot product definition to use based on their use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that by having the complex dot product definition and two vectors, we can normalize them and then apply the dot product between them to find whether it equals $1$ or $-1,$ in which case they’re parallel. This is for the parallel case.
For the orthogonality condition, there’s the link on the comments that explains it.
For the coplanarity, it looks like we can simply do the triple scalar product with a given dot product definition (anti linear in its first argument or anti linear in its second argument).